# No entity audit page when using the audit module

Tags: module, jhipster

I am on the 2.27.0 version of JHipster and installed the entity audit module as described on the module page.

When I change an entity the audit is added to the 'jhi_entity_audit_event' table in my database, so I know the module works.

The problem I have is that the 'Entity audit' button in the 'Administration' tab doesn't respond. When I hover over it I see the /#/entityAudits ref but when I click it the 'Administration' tab just closes again. The other buttons in the tab (Metrics, API, Logs, etc.) do work as intended.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this might have to do with the install of the 'material design' module. 
On a clean project without this module I had no issues.